# Wordpress: after_setup_theme not loading after theme setup

Tags: wordpress, function, installation, undefined

In a plugin I've done an `add_action( 'after_setup_theme' , 'some_funct' );` and then the plugin calls a function named in the theme's functions.php file.

It should work! It came in after "theme setup"! Yet its saying **undefined function**!!! I'm living in the twighlight zone.

Is there any instances or reasons after_setup_theme would disobey the idea of loading ***after*** theme setup?

---*Interestingly out of the 30 sites running this, only one of them is pulling this stunt. Very strange - I have never seen it before.*

Comment: try giving some priority to this action like add_action( 'after_setup_theme' , 'some_funct' , '5');

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I switched the priority a few times...down to "1" but to no avail. That was a good idea though.

The thing I think is very strange is that ONE host is doing this...the others are managing things the way I programmed.

Comment: Anyone have any other observations?

Comment: What is the exact error? "call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback ..." ?
Anyway, its likely that code in the theme's functions.php is not available at the exec time of the plugin, try moving the fn to the plugin becasue that setup doesn't make much sense anyway.